# Rails Slim - unexpected indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm using slim-rails gem for my rails application and I'm having some trouble to use layouts/application.html.slim. The file is simple as bellow:

```
html
  head
    title RailsProjetoBase
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  body
    = yield
```

I'm getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:11:1: unexpected indentation
```

for stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag. If I remove those, it works, but doesn't makes sense. Checked and my editor (sublime 3) didn't insert wrong tabs or spaces. Also tried to "Convert all tabs to spaces/tabs" and nothing. I use the layout like that in another project and works correctly. I'm using rails 5. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably it's the spaces on `stylesheet_link_tag`?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer already tried to remove them. Also, tried to put just "stylesheet_link_tag 'application'" and ignore the other params. Didn't worked. If i put only stylesheet_link_tag, it works. Bizarre

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer: the problem wasn't actually on my layout file. Was on asset.rb. There, when I define the assets to precompile, there was difference between tabs/spaces. Hope this helps someone!